# Best way for form action?

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, oop, model-view-controller

I just started using Code Igniter framework and also just started learning on PHP OOP. I came across something when coding for the forms.

In a form if I have two buttons that would lead to different pages, what would be the most suitable way to do it? I found two ways. The first is to have a dynamic action/link, let's call it method A:

Method A

Variable $form_link is 'form_link'.

(View) main_user_view.php

```
<?php echo form_open($form_link); ?>
<?php echo form_button($add_user_button); ?>
<?php echo form_button($delete_user_button); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

(Controller) User.php

```
public function form_link()
{   
    // Value of button clicked
    $form_submitted = $this->input->post('submit_form'); 

    if($form_submitted == 'add_user')
    {
        redirect('User/add_user');
    }
    elseif($form_submitted == 'delete_user')
    {
        redirect('User/delete_user');
    }
    elseif($form_submitted == 'back')
    {
        redirect('User');
    }
}
```

And the other way is instead of having a second button I would use an anchor and make an absolute path for it.

Method B

Variable $form_link is 'add_user' which is a function in the controller.

(View) main_user_view.php

```
<?php echo form_open($form_link); ?>
<?php echo form_button($add_user_button); ?>
<?php echo anchor('add_delete_user/delete_users_view', 'Delete', array('class'=>'btn btn-info', 'role'=>'button'));?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

The only problem I have with method A is that if in the form I have input fields, I cannot get the data through `POST` as `redirect` does not carry over the data to other functions. I resolved that by using method B where the anchor would lead to the function I want whereby I can get the `POST` data.

So my main question is, should I use method B instead whenever I have two or more buttons in a form?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use button names for form post actions,

```
public function form_link()
{   
    if($this->input->post('add_user'))
    {
        redirect('User/add_user');
    }
    if($this->input->post('delete_user'))
    {
        redirect('User/delete_user');
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this is not part of my question, thanks for this. Was having a problem with IE 10 where it won't load. However the main question is which of the methods (that I've stated above) would be best?

Comment: The smart way is Method B. For method A you have to differentiate the form post actions .  Method B, you don't need to specify the form action..

Answer (score 0):

What my opinion is also to use the Method B. To make the URL more nicer you can use custom routing (which is located at '`application/config/routes.php`')

Comment: Why would you use method B? I need some sort of an explanation.